# Matchmaking Bot : Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I keep getting this error. Its rare but still there. If 2 user at the nearly same time press accept and the other pressed decline the error occurs..
its just on these Step i think..
Its a bot that just match 2 player with each other to play ranked or friendlys.
Im grateful for every tip or help on these.

```
  if (interaction.customId == 'accept') {
    //accept button logic here
    const matchedPlayer = matched.find(player => player.player1.ownerId === interaction.user.id || player.player2.ownerId === interaction.user.id && player.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id || player.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id);
    let ownerPlayer;
    let player1;
    let player2;
    if (matchedPlayer) {
      
      
      if (matchedPlayer.player1.accept == undefined && matchedPlayer.player2.accept == undefined) { 
        
        if (matchedPlayer.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player1.name === interaction.user.username) {
          ownerPlayer = matchedPlayer.player1;
          matchedPlayer.player1.accept = true;
          await interaction.update({embeds: [wait4AcceptText], components: [cancelButton]}); 
          // await player1.edit({embeds: [wait4AcceptText], components: [cancelButton]}); 
        } else if (matchedPlayer.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player2.name === interaction.user.username) {
          ownerPlayer = matchedPlayer.player2;
          matchedPlayer.player2.accept = true;
          await interaction.update({embeds: [wait4AcceptText], components: [cancelButton]}); 
         
          // await player2.edit({embeds: [wait4AcceptText], components: [cancelButton]});
        }
      } else {
        matchedPlayer.player1.accept = true;
        matchedPlayer.player2.accept = true;
      }
      
      if (matchedPlayer.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player1.name === interaction.user.username || matchedPlayer.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player2.name === interaction.user.username) {
        if (matchedPlayer.player1.accept && matchedPlayer.player2.accept) {
          await interaction.showModal(modal); 
          if (matchedPlayer.player1.ownerId == interaction.user.id) {
            player2 = await matchedPlayer.player2.interaction.fetchReply();
            await player2.edit({embeds: [wait4IdText], components: [cancelButton]}); 
          } else {
            player1 = await matchedPlayer.player1.interaction.fetchReply();
          await player1.edit({embeds: [wait4IdText], components: [cancelButton]});
          }
          playing.push(matchedPlayer);
          matched.pop(matchedPlayer);
        } 
      } 
    }
  }

  if (interaction.customId == 'decline' || interaction.customId == 'cancel') {
    //decline button logic here
    const selectPlayer  = selection.find(player => player.ownerId === interaction.user.id && player.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id);
    const queuePlayer   = queue.find(player => player.ownerId === interaction.user.id && player.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id);
    const playingPlayer = playing.find(player => player.player1.ownerId === interaction.user.id || player.player2.ownerId === interaction.user.id && player.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id || player.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id);
    const waitingPlayer = waiting.find(player => player.ownerId === interaction.user.id && player.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id);
    const matchedPlayer = matched.find(player => player.player1.ownerId === interaction.user.id || player.player2.ownerId === interaction.user.id && player.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id || player.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id);
    let ownerPlayer;
    let playingOwner;
    let player1;
    let player2;

    if(matchedPlayer) {
      player1 = await matchedPlayer.player1.interaction.fetchReply();
      player2 = await matchedPlayer.player2.interaction.fetchReply();
      if (matchedPlayer.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player1.name === interaction.user.username) {
        ownerPlayer = matchedPlayer.player1;
      } else if (matchedPlayer.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player2.name === interaction.user.username) {
        ownerPlayer = matchedPlayer.player2;
      }
    }

    if(playingPlayer) {
      player1 = await playingPlayer.player1.interaction.fetchReply();
      player2 = await playingPlayer.player2.interaction.fetchReply();
      if (playingPlayer.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && playingPlayer.player1.name === interaction.user.username) {
        playingOwner = playingPlayer.player1;
      } else if (playingPlayer.player2.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && playingPlayer.player2.name === interaction.user.username) {
        playingOwner = playingPlayer.player2;
      }
    }

    if (selectPlayer) {
      selection.pop(selectPlayer);
      interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
    } else if (queuePlayer) {
      queue.pop(queuePlayer); 
      interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
    } else if (playingOwner) {
      if (playingPlayer.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && playingPlayer.player1.name === interaction.user.username) {
        player2.edit({embeds: [otherCancelText], components: []});
        interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
      } else {
        player1.edit({embeds: [otherCancelText], components: []});
        interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
      }
      playing.pop(playingPlayer);
    } else if (waitingPlayer) {
      waiting.pop(waitingPlayer);
      interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
    } else if (ownerPlayer) {
      if (matchedPlayer.player1.interactionId === interaction.message.interaction.id && matchedPlayer.player1.name === interaction.user.username) {
        player2.edit({embeds: [otherCancelText], components: []});
        await interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
      } else {
        player1.edit({embeds: [otherCancelText], components: []});
        await interaction.update({embeds: [cancelSearchText], components: []});
      }
      matched.pop(matchedPlayer);
    }

  }
```

I already had these error but it just solved it by deleting it cause it wasnt necessary.